# vscode/visual studio make text alphanumeric and lowercase - either extension or search and replace

Tags: visual-studio-code, regexp-replace

e.g I have a string.

```
{28C9A666-3FC5-4E8F-A31F-D8854DB68666}
```

Now I want to make the above string into

```
28c9a6663fc54E8fd31fd8854dB68666
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The first part of this answer assumes you are using the Find/Replace in a the current file widget, NOT search/Replace across files.  The `\l` option is not working as expected replacing across files.  I actually think there is a bug but see at the end I found a form which does work in the search/replace across multiple files panel.

You can try this (in the Find widget)

find: `([A-Z])|-`
replace: `\l$1`

or

find: `([A-Z])|[-{}]` if you want to get rid of the `{}` as well.

You will have to have the `Match Case` option enabled on the Find Widget.

or

find: `(\w)|[-{}]`
replace: `\l$1`

And you don't have to have the `Match Case` option enabled.  It just matches every alphanumeric character and replaces it by its lowercased version - which for a digit is the same.

And you probably want to **select the string first**, and then enable the `Find In Selection` option as well.  And of course, enable the `Use Regular Expression` option too.

The find will capture in group 1 all uppercase letters.  It will also match the hyphens and {}'s if you wish but do nothing with them, so those will be effectively removed from the result.

The replace consists of `\l` (that's a lowercase L) which tells vscode to lowercase the following capture group - which are your capital letters.

---

And for searching across multiple files, try this:

find: `\{*([^-{}]*)[-{}]`
replace: `\L$1`          // use a capital L here

vscode doesn't like replacing a non-captured but matched character with `\L` for some reason.

---

Sample keybinding to run this find and replace:

Put this into your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "alt+f",
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "editor.actions.findWithArgs",
        "args": {
          "searchString": "(\\w)|[-{}]",  // note double-escape
          "isRegex": true,
          "replaceString": "\\l$1"   // doubl-escape necessary
        }
      },
      "editor.action.replaceAll",
    ]
  },
}
```

The `editor.actions.findWithArgs` by itself will populate the Find Widget with the queries but not actually run the replace.  The `editor.action.replaceAll` will run all the replacements for the current file.  If you want to just populate the Find Widget and trigger the `replaceAll` yourself use this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+f",
  "command": "editor.actions.findWithArgs",
  "args": {
      
    "isRegex": true,
    "searchString": "(\\w)|[-{}]",
    "replaceString": "\\l$1"

  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks Mark :) 
find: (\w)|[-{}] 
replace: \l$1 

Worked well for me. Now is it possible to do this with a keyboard shortcut so that I don't have to remember these or is there an extension that will remember this for me. 

Or what would be even better is an external app or clipboard manager that can do this for me. That way I will be able to use this for any application. e.g visual studio, visual studio code, excel , word etc.

Comment: Yes, there are a number of ways to assign that to a keybinding.  I showed one in the answer.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks a ton Mark :)

Comment: If we can continue the answers for 
what would be even better is an external app or clipboard manager that can do this for me. That way I will be able to use this for any application. e.g visual studio, visual studio code, excel , word etc. If I can also do expand into sentences and snippets and also have chatgpt integration into it, then that would be great.

I currently use Ditto, pretty great. I will also look into adding this into ditto and share answers here if I find any.